# "Rotate" classes in JQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there a build in way to "Rotate" a list of classes in JQuery similar to toggle class?

For example:

```
$("#MyElt").rotateClass("Cl1 Cl2 Cl3");
$("#MyElt").rotateClass("Cl1 Cl2 Cl3");
$("#MyElt").rotateClass("Cl1 Cl2 Cl3");
$("#MyElt").rotateClass("Cl1 Cl2 Cl3");
```

The status of the class on MYElt after each call would be:

```
Cl1
Cl2
Cl3
NO CLASS
```

Comment: Are you looking for horizontal rotate or vertical rotate?

Comment: @SivaCharan Not a visual rotation, more of a cycling through a list of classes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Rotating elements through a set of classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402350/jquery-rotating-elements-through-a-set-of-classes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your quick reference, I have pasted the code from [jQuery: Rotating elements through a set of classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8402527/500725).

I think, this should help you.

```
$.fn.rotateClass(/* pass multiple class names here */) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if (this.hasClass(arguments[i])) {
            this.removeClass(arguments[i]));
            i++;
            if (i >= arguments.length) {
                i = 0;
            }
            this.addClass(arguments[i]);
            return(this);
        }
    }
    // none found so set the first class
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
        this.addClass(arguments[0]);
    }
    return(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That will teach me to use Google search rather than the SO search.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$.fn.rotateClass = function() { ...`?

Comment: Check also my version of the plugin here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14637729/1329367

Answer (score 0):

Using `hasClass()` and `toggleClass`, you can make your own.